# Insert new Line while storing text file using c#

Tags: c#, file, text, newline, store

I got two string Latitude and longitude of a place from code. I am using c#.I want to store it with a new line order. Like I want to save latitude and longitude

```
Lat: 94.000
Lon: 54.1010
```

I have tried this code in this way. But it is not working at all

```
Lat_text.Text = Latitude.ToString();
Lon_Text.Text = Longitude.ToString();
File.WriteAllText(path,"Lat:" +Lat_text.Text +"\n"+"Lon:"+ Lon_Text.Text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` for Unix platforms. Use `\r\n` instead. Or better use [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) instead.

```
File.WriteAllText(path, "Lat:" + Lat_text.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Lon:" + Lon_Text.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Soner Gönül's answer you could use:

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, new[]{"Lat: " + Lat_text.Text, "Lon:" + Lon_Text.Text});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. @Rene